# Bulk optimization of images

Tags: image, optimization, image-processing, compression, image-compression

My client uploaded about 500 images to the server, none of which are optimized. Most are only 800x600 or so yet are weighing in as 700 KB - 1.5 MB files. Obviously there is a lot of room for optimization here. I tried doing something locally http://imageoptim.com/), but it's maxing out my laptop and taking way too long to churn through. I tried doing something server side (with http://lyncd.com/2009/03/imgopt-lossless-optimize-png-jpeg/) on my VPS, but that also seems to be taking way too long (we're talking 9 hours to go through 30 images).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Something like the (now defunct) smush.it API would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with imageoptim, you can tweak the settings to use different techniques to get it a bit faster.

It shouldn't take too long doing that – typically for me that many images takes around 10 minutes, but it depends on exactly what they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch conversion feature of this application called IrfanView: http://www.irfanview.com/